# How to center a vertical button group with bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Clearly I am missing something in my understanding of the way bootstrap 4 (alpha) handles these things. I have tried all kinds of wrappers and class modifications and style additions, but I cannot find a way to centre a stack of buttons in a column.

```css
.starter-template {}
/* Buttons */
.btn.center {display: block; margin: 1rem auto;} 


/* Center Button Group Vertical */
.btn-group-vertical.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.australian-art-gallery.com/g/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="starter-template">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow;">
<div class="block-center text-center" style="margin: auto;">
<div class="btn-group-vertical center" style="margin: auto;">
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-auto"  href="find_artist.htm" title="Australian Artists"  target="_self" >Find an Artist</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary " href="find_gallery.htm" title="Australian Galleries"  target="_self" >Find a Gallery</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary " href="find_event.htm" title="Australian Exhibitions"  target="_self" >Find an Exhibition</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary " href="cgi-bin/v_prizes.pl"  title="Australian Art Prizes"  target="_self" >Find an Art Prize</a>
</div></div>
</div>

  <div class="col-sm-4"  style="background-color: lime;">Other Stuff
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"  style="background-color: pink;">More other stuff
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>  </div>
```

Obviously there is a mess of attempts here all bundled into one. Just trying to demonstrate all the things I have tried!

Comment: Can you upload your code into a snippet?

Comment: I have done that. Thanks.

Comment: Works in this codepen -> http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/mrNVPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay away from inline-styles `<div style="...">`. Adding display: block; to the following should resolve the issue for you.

```
.btn-group-vertical.center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Have a look at my codepen example http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/mrNVPG

Comment: Yes that works thankyou, but the link to codepen is to a different solution.

Comment: @Melchester, yes sorry. It's not exactly the same as what you had, but the basics are there.

Comment: great work Chris